# Proof that Thomae's function is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be $0$ if x is irrational and $1/q$ if $x=p/q$ in lowest terms. If $x$ is rational then $f$ is clearly not continuous hence not differentiable. For some irrational $a$, $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ or equivalently $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists. Suppose $a=n.a_1 a_2…$ be the decimal expansion of $a$ and h rational. Then $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=0$, keeping $h$ of the desired form. Construct a sequence $h_1=-0.00…0a_{n+1}a_{n+2}…,$$h_2=-0.00…0a_{n+2}…$ so on. Hence $\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}$ $=\frac{\frac{1}{10^n}}{\frac{-0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}…}{10^n}}$. Now what do I do?

I came across this problem in Spivak's calculus textbook.

Comment: You seem to be overusing $n$ in two or three ways.  It cannot simultaneously be fixed (as in $a,h_1,x_1$) and the index of the sequence (as in $h_n, x_n$).  Can you rewrite it using another letter (e.g. $m$) for anywhere you had a fixed $n$ so to not mix them?  Also, your final computation seems to say $f(x_n)=x_n$ which cannot possibly be true for all $n$.

Comment: If you search Spivak chapter/exercise number, I'm 99.9% certain you should find this.  I saw it the other day, even

Comment: The notation abuse I'll fix that part. Concerning $f(x_n)$ then $f(x_n)\geq\frac{1}{10^n}$

Comment: I do mathematics as a hobby. So there is really not a lot of people around to help me out. It would mean a ton if someone can help me out a bit. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the basic idea, the problem is mainly one of technique.

First, note that if $x\to a$ through irrational numbers $x$ then $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\equiv 0$$ so that if $f$ is differentiable at some irrational $a$, we must have $f'(a)=0$.  I think this is what you meant to say, but it's hard to understand what you wrote.

Next, we want to look at a sequence of rational values that approaches $a$.  Let $a = a_0.a_1a_2\dots a_n\dots$ be the decimal expansion of $a$ (as has been pointed out in a comment, you shouldn't use $n$ as both the integer part of $a$ and as an index.)  Define a sequence $b_n$ by the decimal expansion
$$b_n =a_0.a_1a_2\dots a_n$$

Now we need to estimate $$\frac{f(b_n)-f(a)}{b_n-a}=\frac{f(b_n)}{b_n-a}$$ We know that $0<{a-b_n}<10^{-n}$ so that $$\left\lvert\frac{1}{b_n-a}\right\rvert>10^n$$  Also, $b_n$ can be written as a fraction with a denominator of $10^n$, so in lowest terms, the denominator is $\leq 10^n$.  By definition of $f$, $f(b_n)\geq10^{-n}$.  Putting this all together, we have
$$\left\lvert\frac{f(b_n)-f(a)}{b_n-a}\right\rvert=\frac{b_n}{a-b_n}>10^{-n}10^n=1$$ and the limit cannot possibly be $0$.

I think I see all these ideas in your question, but you need to practice writing math more clearly.  It's not at all easy.  Just as you look for easier ways to do a problem once you've solved it, you should look for ways to rewrite your proofs more clearly.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, and thanks a lot.